# Share a common script across Repos

Tags: mercurial, symlink

My team's source control's directory structure involves many custom repos which connect to a large 3rd party application. They contain scripts which run simply by existing in a specific folder inside of this application. Currently as developers switch between projects/repos they copy and paste their directory into this repo and delete the other repos (or move them to a separate "inactive" directory). This (clearly) occasionally leads to problems with files being missed, or the directory not having been properly "cleaned" between repo switches.

In an attempt to come up with a more fool-proof way of handling this issue I've written a script which will create a symlink from a repo to the 3rd party app's "scripts" folder and remove other symlinks which had previously been created there. This will create a two step process of update + run script (though in the future I may hook this script directly into mercurial to make switching repos a single command.)

First question: Does this symlink system make sense, or is there a better way to do this?

Second question: How should I effectively share this file between repos? My first thought is to use a subrepo, but that seems like overkill for a simple script and it would need to be manually included in every repo.

Please note: a single monolithic repo isn't really an option as I don't really want to create that much churn in the system to implement this. Also, we do currently have a core library which is a subrepo inside our custom repos, if this makes a difference. I thought about storing it in the core repo, but I couldn't guarantee where inside of any one repo that script was being run from.

Comment: When you say **submodule**, you are talking about a [subrepository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository), right?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'm coming from a Git background and get the two terms mixed up. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, but each has backdraws:

- You can make all the projects a sub-repo of the one which contains the script and helper files to build the projects
- You can indeed make the script-repo a sub-repo of each project.
- You could simply pull the script repo into each project and merge it with the project. Mercurial will warn you that it's unrelated, but sure, it is and you hopefully know what you do. If you do this, you want to make sure that the script repo has a folder structure such that it is compatible with all your projects so that the merge is effortless. Should the script repo experience updates, simply pull again and merge with your project's development tree.

The sub-repo approach has backdraws in that sense that you start to use sub-repo which have rough edges in the workflow. Thus I suggest the pull and merge. It gives you a bit duplication (as it then exists in each repo), alas, it's one script.

Comment: and never merge back to the script. So perhaps a hook to guard for it

Comment: The problem is that we currently have too many repos for our own good (we're working on reducing them, but still currently have a few dozen). This script is something that is fairly simple at the moment, but the expectation is that it will start handling more build cases for us and I want to be able to update it easily without needing to merge into each repo.

It sounds like either the first or second case would make the most sense given this, but I agree that it still makes for a rough workflow.

Comment: Maybe use a hybrid approach: keep the (generic) script in a separate repo. And only store in each project's repo a config file which is read by that script which tells it what needs to know (project type, maybe some path or tool config or what-not). On my CI (jenkins) server I have a build script along with some tools in a separate project. The 'real' projects have a project-specific config file which tells the build script how to handle the project (there are different project types). Thus the build script gets a path and reads the config file from it and everything else follows from that.